# Forward message similar to webhook from a Studio Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have the ability to receive the full incoming message from setting a url in the number section under "A message comes in" to Webhook and entering my url. I would like my messages to be processed in a Studio Flow first. Is there any way from the flow I could then pass it out to a webhook url? I know the webhook sends this info in json, but I'm not sure if I can build all of this data with the html widget. Any idea for how I could do it?

```
(
    [inbound] => 
    [ToCountry] => US
    [ToState] => OK
    [SmsMessageSid] => xxx
    [NumMedia] => 0
    [ToCity] => NOBLE
    [FromZip] => 73003
    [SmsSid] => xxx
    [FromState] => OK
    [SmsStatus] => received
    [FromCity] => EDMOND
    [Body] => Test
    [FromCountry] => US
    [To] => +xxx
    [ToZip] => 73068
    [NumSegments] => 1
    [MessageSid] => xxx
    [AccountSid] => xxx
    [From] => +xxx
    [ApiVersion] => 2010-04-01
)
```

Comment: When you say "the html widget" are you referring to the "HTTP Request" widget?

Comment: Yes, that is the one.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could certainly pass it to a Studio Flow first, as you describe, and then use the HTTP request to send all the data onto a webhook URL of your own.

To send all the data onto your own URL, you would need to add all the parameters to the widget too. You'll [find all that data in the `trigger` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#context-variables) within the flow.